# StringBuilder replacing specific characters

Tags: java

I want to mask certain parts of an email address, and not to use `regex` at all.

Example:

> "testing@gmail.com" should become "t*****g@g***l.com"

Where the characters in the email (barring the first and last) become masked out, and no change to the domain.

```
        String email = "testing@gmail.com";
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(email);
        int mp = sb.lastIndexOf("@");
        int dp = sb.substring(mp).indexOf(".");
        for (int i = 1; i < sb.length(); i++) {
            if (i != mp && i != mp - 1 && i != mp + 1 && i != ((mp + dp) - 1) && i < (dp + mp)) {
                sb.setCharAt(i, '*');
            }
        }
```

I know this will fail if something unusual such as an `@` in the domain, but that's fine.

It's mainly the `if` statement that seems awful to me, and wondering if I could shorten it to much simpler logic.

[Online Demo](https://ideone.com/2iH9Zk)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's two consecutive ranges that you want to get replaced with `*`. So, I'd do two loops like:

```
    for (int i = 1; i < mp-1; i++) {
        sb.setCharAt(i, '*');
    }
    for (int i = mp+2; i < mp+dp-1; i++) {
        sb.setCharAt(i, '*');
    }
```

And add some sanity checks that the `@` and `.` characters are present.

Comment: Thanks. I initially had two loops (albeit maybe not as tidy as this) but though squeezing it into one might be better although looking at the two of them now, this is certainly more readable.

Answer (score 2):

As another answer pointed out,
it's definitely easier to read if you use two loops.

One thing I want to add on top of that,
to find the first `.` appearing after `@`,
instead of calling `sb.substring(...).indexOf(...)` which may create a new object,
it will be better to use the 2-parameter version of the `.indexOf` method:

```
int dp = sb.indexOf(".", mp);
```